# Javascript text replacemant same way like "Emiliy is away" game. Onkeydown issue

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making art web project where I wan't to replace user inputed text to my own phrases in infnity.

Similar way like in game "Emily is away", but that will be only one phrase repeat in infinity.

Something like this:
"text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text"

When user will be typing, the result will be always the same phrase.

My code looks this way:

```js
  function myFunction() {
    result.innerHTML = "TEXT";
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction()">
<div id="result"></div>
```

I will be really glad for help.

Comment: @lucas that doesn't make any sense. In that case, the function would never be executed at all.

Comment: yes @ADyson you are right

Comment: For the next time: Only add tags that are relevant to your question/issue. I removed the PHP tag since it's completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? It will append the string to the existing output, rather than replacing it:

```js
function myFunction() {
    result.innerHTML += "TEXT ";
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction()">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot about +=. I'm really glad for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myInput = document.querySelectorAll('input');

myInput.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
    result.innerHTML += "TEXT ";
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I'm really glad for your help.